# Twig: Show specific entry by url

Tags: templating, slug

my url looks like this:

```
domain.tld/slug-1/slug-2/variable
```

And in Twig it shall look for an entry with the slug slug-1 and show it, then an entry with the slug slug-2 and show it and look up for a global where the name of the global is variable.

How do I do this? I found:

```
{% set entry = craft.entries.section('section_handle').slug('my_slug') %}
```

But how do I tell Twig whats the first and whats the second slug?

There are always 2 slugs and one variable.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the parts of your URL using the `getSegment()` function. https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/craft.request#getSegment

Then use the `slug` parameter and the criteria model’s `first()` method to grab the entry. Global Sets are already preloaded, to access a set dynamically grab it from the `_context` variable.

```
{% set entryA = craft.entries.slug(craft.request.getSegment(1)).first() %}
{% set entryB = craft.entries.slug(craft.request.getSegment(2)).first() %}
{% set globalSet = _context[craft.request.getSegment(3)] ?? null %}

{% if not entryA or not entryB or not globalSet %}
    {% exit 404 %}
{% endif %}

{{ entryA.title }} - {{ globalSet.myField }}
```